# Peak detection using an analog switch

Tags: switches, analog, multiplier

I have a sinusoidal signal of 500kHz with 1V(peak to peak). I need to peak-detect this signal. I found out that using OPAMPs and diodes can not provide a good peak detection.

It was pointed out to me that if I use signal multiplication between the signal I want to measure and a signal of the same frequency, I can detect the peak that I am looking for rather easily.

I found out that there are IC multipliers that are expensive for the cause of my design. So I was thinking about using analog switches, but I am not sure if/how is that possible.

Please share some knowledge with me.

Comment: Do you need to detect frequency? Maximum point? Zero crossing detection is easier to do, if you want frequency. It is not entirely clear what is your end goal.

Comment: What do you want to know about the peak? Its timing, its amplitude, or both? Please share some context about your application with us.

Comment: Sure its possible, but if a *multiplier* gives you grief, the signal conditioning required to drive the switch's logical "on/off" input will give you grief too.

Comment: Opamps and diodes can provide very good peak detection if you choose the right devices so -1 for blatent ignorance in making that statement. I made one that works OK at 40 MHz.

Comment: What accuracy? within 10mV over 0.5volt peak input? what DC component?

Answer (score 2):

**The hard part everyone fails to understand is you need a spec. for any design.**

### Peak Detectors

Is it Peak and hold, Peak and decay or Peak following on every cycle or every half cycle, half wave or precision full wave rectified.

Is it Absolute Peak + Noise or Average Peak ( noise rejected) by defining LPF Band and group delay.?

Tolerance and delay for Peak time is easy, the after this, many choices for deciding when lower peaks will be tracked. **THis is is essentially the Bandwidth of the desired output**, which can be 1st order LPF, 2nd order or all the way up to the carrier frequency with precision peak following on cycle by cycle basis.

**Normally one defines the signal or channel bandwidth and then decides which approach to take.**

1) decay slew rate or BW  between peaks 
2) or sample and hold the peaks using the derivation pulse from a 90 deg shifted sync. clock. to drive a comparator between signal and Vpk with a S&H ( 4066 )
3) or a derivative of carrier for 90 deg phase shift and use

HDD servos use dibits on either side off by 1/2 track and then use a differential peak to peak in various methods   between a pair of pulses to determine the Position Error Signal (PES) for servo feedback then reset between pulses and then filter the result with minimal prop delays but use jitter rejection ( Kalman etc) filters to give the fastest servo response on servo pulse peak detection.

If you have a carrier clock, it makes it easier (PLL) , otherwise, Peak detect using  and decay.

As you see awareness of all the options, and deciding input/output behavior or WRITTEN SPECS by you is the best way to design anything. (**Learning how to know what you need, and write simple specs, is the hard part.**.. and that includes Professors and post-grad students but not experienced Designers.)